# Remove/hide total_sales WooCommerce custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to remove the `total_sales` custom field when displaying `the_meta` for a product?

I can change the entry in the editor to another name and value, but it magically appears again and won't be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the 'the_meta_key' filter for this. you have a few options, and of course you can combine them.

Control what to hide with CSS

```
add_filter( 'the_meta_key' , 'class_custom_fields', 10, 3);

function classes_custom_fields($string, $key, $value){
    return str_replace('<li>','<li class="' . str_replace(' ', '-', $key). '">',$string);
}

<style>
ul.post-meta li.total_sales{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Control what to hide via PHP & CSS

```
add_filter( 'the_meta_key' , 'hide_custom_fields', 10, 3);

function hide_custom_fields($string, $key, $value){
    $hide_keys = array(
        'total_sales'
    );
    if(in_array(strtolower($key), $hide_keys)){
        return str_replace('<li>','<li class="hide">',$string);
    }
    return $string;
}
<style>
    .hide{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Control what to Display with PHP

```
add_filter( 'the_meta_key' , 'allowed_custom_fields', 10, 3);

function allowed_custom_fields($string, $key, $value){

    $allowed_keys = array(
        'attribute one',
    );

    if(in_array(strtolower($key), $allowed_keys)){
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Control what not to Display with PHP

```
add_filter( 'the_meta_key' , 'disallowed_custom_fields', 10, 3);


function disallowed_custom_fields($string, $key, $value){

    $disallowed_keys = array(
        'total_sales'
    );
    if(!in_array(strtolower($key), $disallowed_keys)){
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `total_sales` ends up as the last list item of it's `ul` group (in this case `ul.post-meta`), just enter: `ul.post-meta li:last-child{
    display: none;
}`